# Item command cannot edit another item in the list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sidebar

I have a sidebar (in a C# WPF program) that should display 4 "different" buttons (They are actually 2 different styles, which both have another style for the active state). The sidebar consists of an ItemsControl. I've now managed to create a list where the correct style is used based on an enum value (as shown below). Here's a small question: Can I do it this way, or should I rewrite it, and if so, how could something like this be built? Keywords or something that I have to look at are enough for me.

My real question now is: I have bound a command to every button, nothing complicated at first. The command now sets its own state to NormalActive for testing purposes. The 1st item in this list should be set from LiveActive to Live (so that you always see the currently selected item as you know it). And here's the problem: The button can set its own state, so when I click on button 3, the state of button 3 is set from Normal to NormalActive. But what doesn't happen is the change from LiveActive to Active from the 1st button. Even if I output the current state to the console before and after the change, it returns LiveActive for both. I also tried invoking the whole thing into the dispatcher if I'm not in the UI thread for some reason, it didn't work. So the button can set its own state, but not the one of another. But I don't get an error message or anything. Also the setter method of the property is called, it just doesn't change it. What could be the reason?

**PluginListControl:**

```
<Grid DataContext="{x:Static local:PluginListDesignModel.Instance}">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:PluginListItemControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**PluginListItemControl:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PluginTile" DataType="{x:Type local:PluginListItemViewModel}">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource PluginTile}" Content="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SetStateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PluginActiveTile" DataType="{x:Type local:PluginListItemViewModel}">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource PluginActiveTile}" Content="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SetStateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PluginLiveTile" DataType="{x:Type local:PluginListItemViewModel}">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource PluginLiveTile}" Content="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SetStateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PluginActiveLiveTile" DataType="{x:Type local:PluginListItemViewModel}">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource PluginActiveLiveTile}" Content="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SetStateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ContentControl d:DataContext="{x:Static local:PluginListItemDesignModel.Instance}">

    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginTile}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginTile}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginActiveTile}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginLiveTile}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginActiveLiveTile}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>

</ContentControl>
```

**PluginListItemViewModel:** (The ViewModel for each list item)

```
public class PluginListItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PluginTileStates State { get; set; }
    public ICommand SetStateCommand { get; set; }

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public PluginListItemViewModel()
    {
        SetStateCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SetState());
    }

    #endregion

    private void SetState()
    {
        PluginListDesignModel.Instance.Items[0].State = PluginTileStates.Live;
        State = PluginTileStates.NormalActive;
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new WPF project, .NET Framework 4.6.1 (Visual Studio 2017).
2. Replace the grid in MainWindow with the following:

---

```
<Grid DataContext="{x:Static local:ListViewModel.Instance}">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ListItemControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

3. Add a new UserControl named ListItemControl and replace the grid with:

---

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Tile" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ActiveTile" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PluginTile" DataType="{x:Type local:ListItemViewModel}">
        <Button Width="100" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource Tile}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SetStateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PluginActiveTile" DataType="{x:Type local:ListItemViewModel}">
        <Button Width="100" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource ActiveTile}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SetStateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginTile}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginTile}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PluginActiveTile}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

4. Add a new class called BaseViewModel and replace class with:

---

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

5. Add new class called ListItemViewModel and replace class with:

---

```
public enum TileStates
{
    Normal = 0,
    Active = 1
}

public class ListItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public TileStates State { get; set; }

    public ICommand SetStateCommand { get; set; }

    public ListItemViewModel()
    {
        SetStateCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
          {
              ListViewModel.Instance.Items[0].State = TileStates.Normal;
              State = TileStates.Active;
          });
    }
}
```

6. Add new class called ListViewModel and replace class with:

---

```
public class ListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public static ListViewModel Instance => new ListViewModel();

    public List<ListItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new List<ListItemViewModel>
    {
        new ListItemViewModel
        {
            State = TileStates.Active
        },
        new ListItemViewModel
        {
            State = TileStates.Normal
        }
    };
}
```

7. Add new class called RelayCommand and replace class with:

---

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action mAction;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    public RelayCommand(Action action)
    {
        mAction = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        mAction();
    }
}
```

8. Install the NuGet-Packages: "Fody v4.0.2" and "PropertyChanged.Fody v2.6.0" (You probably have to restart Visual Studio after installation

If you now press the bottom button, it should get green and the top one should switch to red.

Comment: How do you debug the setter? Is it invoked from somwhere else than your code?

Comment: I have added a private variable. So like this:
private PluginTileStates mState;
public PluginTileStates State { get => mState; set { Console.WriteLine($"Setting to: {value}"); mState = value; }} And I'm of course setting it as State = PluginTileStates.Live;

Comment: So how do you know that it isn't set to `PluginTileStates.Live`? Or do you mean that you don't see the change in the UI? Could you please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Well, on the one hand the style should change, because the value changes (At least theoretically, do this for the first time, maybe I miss something because of the DataTemplates). And on the other hand, as described above, I had the current state output to me, both before and after the change to PluginTileStates.Live . As for the MCVE: I can of course do a small project, but how do I get it in here? Just upload it somewhere and post the link here?

Comment: No, you should include a *minimal* example in your question.

Comment: So I can't really make it any smaller. Now I added it to the question as Steps to Reproduce.

Comment: That's a great example.Thanks. See my answer for a possible solution to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListViewModel.Instance` returns a new instance of the `ListViewModel` class each time it's invoked. It should return the same instance:

```
public static ListViewModel Instance { get; } = new ListViewModel();
```

Comment: Oh my God, such a fatal and at the same time simple mistake... That was the solution to the riddle, thank you very much!